# How to convert a vector<wstring> to a wchar_t**?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I need to create a C compatible (friendly) return type so that my C++ functions can be used to work with C-based functions.

How I can convert a vector of `wstring` to a `wchar_t**` array?

Comment: vector doesnt have a.c_str() member function as far as i know.! I need to convert the whole vector with all of its items to a c based array such as wchar_t** .!

Comment: wstring is a templated instantiation of basic_string<whcar_t>, so it's c_str() function returns wchar_t*. So you convert a vector of basic_string<wchar_t> to a wchar_t* the same way you convert a vector of basic_string<char> to a char*

Comment: @kfsone: No, it returns `wchar_t const*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function for converting a vector of `std::wstring` to a `wchar_t**` based string. It also won't leak any memory because of using that DisposeBuffer(); call unlike other answers.

```
wchar_t ** xGramManipulator::GetCConvertedString(vector< wstring> const &input)
{
    DisposeBuffer();  //This is to avoid memory leak for calling this function multiple times
    cStringArraybuffer = new wchar_t*[input.size()]; //cStringArraybuffer is a member variable of type wchar_t**
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        cStringArraybuffer[i] = new wchar_t[input[i].size()+1];
        wcscpy_s(cStringArraybuffer[i], input[i].size() + 1, input[i].c_str());
        cStringArraySize++;
    }
    return cStringArraybuffer;
}
```

And this is the DisposeBuffer Helper Function to avoid memory leaks:

```
void xGramManipulator::DisposeBuffer(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cStringArraySize; i++)
    {
        delete [] cStringArraybuffer[i];
    }
    delete [] cStringArraybuffer;
    cStringArraybuffer = nullptr;
    cStringArraySize = 0;
}
```

And prior to these allocate a dummy space in your constructor:

```
xGramManipulator::xGramManipulator()
{
    //allocating dummy array so that when we try to de-allocate it in GetCConvertedString(), dont encounter any undefined behavior

    cStringArraybuffer = new wchar_t*[1];
    cStringArraySize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cStringArraybuffer[i] = new wchar_t[1 + 1];
        cStringArraySize++;
    }
}
```

And it's all done.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the wstring vector and add each `wstring::c_str()` to your `wchart_t**` array.

Answer (score 1):

Far better to avoid doing this at all if you possibly can.

If you *really* have no choice, you'd basically do something like allocating an array of pointers, then allocating space for each string, and copying each individual string in the input to the buffer you allocated.

```
wchar_t *dupe_string(std::wstring const &input) { 
    wchar_t *ret = new wchar_t[input.size()+1];
    wcscpy(ret, input.c_str());
    return ret;
}

wchar_t **ruin(std::vector<std::wstring> const &input) {
    wchar_t **trash = new wchar_t*[input.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
       trash[i] = dupe_string(input[i]);
    return trash;
}
```

Based on the comments, however, I have some misgivings about this applying to the current situation though -- this assumes the input is wide strings, which would typically mean UTF-16 or UTF-32/UCS-4. If the input is really in the form of UTF-8, then the storage elements you're dealing with will really be `char`, not `wchar_t`, so your input should be narrow strings (`std::string`) and the matching output `char **` rather than `wchar_t **`.

Comment: Thakyou very much. but c.str() returns a char* pointer while i need wchar_t* since i am dealing with UTF8 based characters. what can i do about it?

Comment: @Hossein: Unless you're also going to do a conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 or UTF-32, you want to use `char`, not `wchar_t`.

Comment: my wstring contents are already converted form a UTF16 to UTF8 and in order to preserved their data i need to use wchar_t.I am not sure i completely got your point ! if i go on and use a char to stored the contents of my wstring str , i believe the data would be lost! right?

Comment: @Hossein: doesn't seem to me you're making much sense. If the data is in UTF-8, then you should be storing it in `char`s, not `wchar_t`s, and in `std::string`, not `std::wstring`. In any case, if what you have is `std::wstring`s, then converting to `wchar_t *`s stays about like above, except you need to change `char` to `wchar_t`, and `string` to `wstring` (oh, and `strcpy` to `wcscpy`).

Comment: I tried to store it in char and string but then the data were trashed.when i used wstring instead everything started to work just fine.I had a question here two days ago about this issue you can have a loot at it at my profile .
Anyway thanks a billion,I'll give it a try and if there was any problem i'll comment.

Comment: @Hossein: I've edited the code to deal with `wchar_t`, `std::wstring`, etc. That doesn't really fit with UTF-8, but rereading the question, it is what you asked about, so, I'll hope it's at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: this only stores one item!! 
and by the way should not we have 
trash[i] = new wchar_t[input[i].size()+1];
trash[i] = dupe_string(input[i]);
what does dupe_string do here? copying each literal into a trash row? or setting a reference ? :-/

Comment: @Hossein: `dupe_string` is included in the code in the answer -- it allocates the memory for the new string, so the caller doesn't need to. Unless I've included a bug I haven't noticed, this should duplicate all the strings in the input, not just one.

Comment: Thanks, How can i free those spaces? i dont have any idea how many times they are going to get called and allocate new space. at first i thought i deallocate them in the destructor, but this will only deal with the last alocated memory for this array! those former allocations wont be available to me to deal with them! :-/ can you help me find a way to deal with memory leak cause by this approach?

Answer (score 1):

wstring is a templated instantiation of basic_string, so its c_str() function returns wchar_t*.

So, you can do something like

```
std::vector<const wchar_t*> pointers;
pointers.reserve(wstrVec.size());
for (auto it = wstrVec.begin(); it != wstrVec.end(); ++it) {
    pointers.push_back(it->c_str());
}

const whcar_t** cptr = pointers.data();
```

Without more context it's difficult to advise the best way to deal with scope/lifetime issues. Are you writing a library (which suggests you have no control over scope) or providing an api for callbacks from C code you are supervising?

A common approach is to provide a sizing api so that the caller can provide a destination buffer of appropriate size:

```
size_t howManyWstrings()
{
    return wstrVec.size();
}

bool getWstrings(const wchar_t** into, size_t intoSize /*in pointers*/)
{
    const size_t vecSize = wstrVec.size();
    if (intoSize < vecSize || into == nullptr)
        return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i) {
        into[i] = wstrVec[i].c_str();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: its local right? and upon returning the value, the variable is destroyed and this is not good

Comment: That's correct, you'll need to establish a way to determine ownership for the C functions, and I would strongly encourage you to mark things as const so that bad things don't happen in C-space.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your C function is expecting a pointer to a `wchar_t` buffer, and to be able to move this pointer around.

Well, this is mostly easy, though you'll have to manage the lifetime of the pointer. To that end, I suggest *not* doing this as a return type (and thus letting C ruin your API, not to mention your code's sanity), but performing this logic at the call site of the C function:

```
/** A function that produces your vector */
std::vector<wchar_t> foo();

/** The C function in question */
void theCFunction(wchar_t**);

int main()
{
   std::vector<wchar_t> v = foo();
   wchar_t* ptr = &v[0];
   theCFunction(&ptr);
}
```

BTW from the question and some comments it sounds like you misunderstand what `char` and `wchar_t` *are* — they sit *below* the encoding layer and if you have UTF-8 then you should be storing each byte of your UTF-8 string as, well, as a single byte. This means using `char`s, as in a `std::string`. Sure, each individual byte in that string will not necessarily represent a single logical unicode character, but then that is not the point of it.

Comment: Actually i want this because i need a dll that can be worked with easily in C#. i couldnt get the C++ dll to work and i am trying to convert the return type to a c compatible type that in c# can be marshaled easily.! i dont know how to pass an array to my c function with c#! what should i do in this case?

Comment: Thanks, by the way do you know how i can convert a char** to a c# counter part? i dont know which type to choose for my function in my c# app!

Comment: @Hossein: 'Fraid not. I think you've just found your next SO question! :-)