# How to convert std:wstring to std::vector<wchar_t>

Tags: c++

If

```
std::wstring word = L"xxxxxxx";
```

Then how to do the following conversion?

```
std::vector<wchar_t> chars = word;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a vector<wstring> to a wchar\_t\*\* ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916842/how-to-convert-a-vectorwstring-to-a-wchar-t)

Comment: I don't think this is a viable duplicate target.

Comment: @Anjan That's a totally different question.

Comment: Others have answered. But it's an odd thing to want to do. A string is essentially a wrapper for a vector of characters and its unusual to need to take the wrapping off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize it with a pair of iterators:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> chars(word.begin(), word.end());
```

The above will not add the null terminator (but if the string contains one, it will be copied). If you want it, initialize the vector with a pair of pointers to the underlying string data instead:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> chars(word.c_str(), word.c_str() + word.size() + 1);
```

Remember to add 1 for the null terminator, otherwise the effect will be the same as in the first example.

Comment: Very nice but I'd be explicit about the treatment of the nul-terminator if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to create it in one go including the null terminator by using the c_str() or data() from the wstring. (In C++11 these are both guaranteed to be null terminated), and then adding size()+1 for the end position, also guaranteed to be well-defined behaviour.

Thus:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> chars( word.c_str(), word.c_str() + word.size() + 1 );
```

(or use data() instead of c_str() but only C++11 onward )

Comment: What's considered the proper behaviour on this site? My answer is less correct than yours if you want the null terminator, but if I edit it to incorporate yours, will it be considered the right thing to do or plagiarism/stealing?

Comment: The proper behaviour on this site is to try to present an answer such that a future person coming to the site with the same question will be able to find the solution. It is not about us and our reputation (something I stopped caring about once I got to 20K)